# Retaining variable with method in python

Tags: python, variables, methods, save

I'm trying to have python recall the 'enstring' variable I set using the 'crypto'  method I created so I can use it in the 'decrypto' method.

```
class encryptString():
    def crypto(self, string):
        enstring = base64.b64encode(string)
        print enstring
    def decrypto(self, enstring):
        destring = base64.b64decode(enstring)
        print destring
```

So, I want 'crypto' to set 'enstring' as the variable for the encoded string. However, when I call the variable after using the 'crypto' method, I get the "enstring is not defined" error.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Also: -posted from my iPhone if code looks weird. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.enstring` both times. Do the same for `destring`. Don't pass `enstring` to `decrypto` as it'll be part of `self`.

```
class encryptString():
    def crypto(self, string):
        self.enstring = base64.b64encode(string)
        print self.enstring
    def decrypto(self):
        self.destring = base64.b64decode(self.enstring)
        print self.destring
```

This way, `enstring` and `destring` are instance attributes, so they're not lost when the `crypto` and `decrypto` methods return.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the class to save `enstring` as a member, then you must assign it to `self.enstring`:

```
class encryptString():

    def __init__(self):
        self.enstring = ''
        self.destring = ''

    def crypto(self, string):
        self.enstring = base64.b64encode(string)
        print self.enstring

    def decrypto(self):
        self.destring = base64.b64decode(self.enstring)
        print self.destring
```

(Avoid using `string` as a variable name.)

Comment: If you initialize them there is no way to tell between "I haven't encrypted yet" and "`crypto` was passed an empty string". `string` is just another module in the standard library, not a built-in, so I think it's fine to use it as a variable name (true, it's not very descriptive, but it's a short method and there is only one thing for it to mean in context).